# Cartopy - Use of "populated_places" NaturalEarthFeature display on Matplotlib map

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, cartopy

I'm working on a map that needs the reference points and labels of city's names and state's names (Brazil and Colombia).  From the web image in Natural Earth page seams that the feature "populated_places" will give me what I need.  I just need to know how to work with it.

In code I have the following:

```
import cartopy.feature as cf
pop = cf.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural',
      name='populated_places', 
      scale='10m', 
      facecolor='none')
```

This part looks like is working because is not given me any error or warning.

---

After that I try to plot it in my map using:
`ax1.scatter('pop.LATITUDE', 'pop.LONGITUDE', projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())`

### I got an attributeError as follow:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-47ca7f66b91e> in <module>
     19 ax1.add_feature(stt, edgecolor='black',facecolor='none')
     20 ax1.add_feature(stt_prv, linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='gray')
---> 21 ax1.scatter('pop.LATITUDE', 'pop.LONGITUDE', projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
     22 
     23 # ax1.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py in scatter(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1435                              '(PlateCarree or RotatedPole).')
   1436 
-> 1437         result = matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1438         self.autoscale_view()
   1439         return result

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1808                         "the Matplotlib list!)" % (label_namer, func.__name__),
   1809                         RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
-> 1810             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1811 
   1812         inner.__doc__ = _add_data_doc(inner.__doc__,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in scatter(self, x, y, s, c, marker, cmap, norm, vmin, vmax, alpha, linewidths, verts, edgecolors, **kwargs)
   4298                 )
   4299         collection.set_transform(mtransforms.IdentityTransform())
-> 4300         collection.update(kwargs)
   4301 
   4302         if colors is None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in update(self, props)
    914 
    915         with cbook._setattr_cm(self, eventson=False):
--> 916             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
    917 
    918         if len(ret):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    914 
    915         with cbook._setattr_cm(self, eventson=False):
--> 916             ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]
    917 
    918         if len(ret):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in _update_property(self, k, v)
    910                 func = getattr(self, 'set_' + k, None)
    911                 if not callable(func):
--> 912                     raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
    913                 return func(v)
    914 

AttributeError: Unknown property projection
```

### This is an edit on Jul 24, 2019

Here is a code that goes into the right plotting direction.

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpr

# Retriving the information from web
stt = cf.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', 
    name='admin_0_boundary_lines_land',
    scale='10m',facecolor='none')
stt_prv = cf.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', 
    name='admin_1_states_provinces_lines',
    scale='10m',facecolor='none')
fname = shpr.natural_earth(resolution='10m', category='cultural', name='populated_places')
reader = shpr.Reader(fname)

# Image desing
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 6))

# Main Map
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 5, (1,4), projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_title('Populated places of the world', fontsize=16)
ax.coastlines()
points = list(reader.geometries())
ax.scatter([point.x for point in points],
           [point.y for point in points],
           transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
           s=0.1, c='r')
ax.add_feature(stt, linewidth=0.2, edgecolor='black')

# Brazil Map
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 5, 5, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-74, -34, -30, 6.1])
ax.set_title('Populated places of BRA', fontsize=8)
ax.coastlines()
points = list(reader.geometries())
ax.scatter([point.x for point in points],
           [point.y for point in points],
           transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
           marker='p',s=10, c='r')
ax.add_feature(stt,     linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='black')
ax.add_feature(stt_prv, linewidth=0.2, edgecolor='black')

# Colombia Map
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 5, 10, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_extent([-65, -80, -5, 13])
ax.set_title('Populated places of COL', fontsize=8)
ax.coastlines()
points = list(reader.geometries())
ax.scatter([point.x for point in points],
           [point.y for point in points],
           transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
           marker='p',s=10, c='r')
ax.add_feature(stt,     linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='black', zorder=0)
ax.add_feature(stt_prv, linewidth=0.2, edgecolor='black', zorder=5)

plt.show()
```

[Result of previous code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xL6l.png)

Comment: The error is unrelated to the first paragraph and title. Check with the documentation on how to plot something in cartopy. Best start with a known example, then only modify the input data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have been working on your recommendation (Please today's edit on question).  I succeed to at least plot the data in the right way.  But still some gaps to label it, countries and city names, and how to color the dots according to population.

Comment: You can post what you need (in the comment above) as a new question. Then, more people will see and help.

Comment: Ok, tks again.
Following are the two questions I would like to solve: Plot the names of the cities and get the symbol of the city location gradually size according to population number.